# Potential of a charged cylinder by using Laplace's equation

Tags: electrostatics, potential, coordinate-systems

When we calculate the electric potential due to charged cylinder by using Laplace's equation $\vec \nabla^2 V=0$, or in the cylindrical coordinate system we can write the divergence as $$\vec \nabla^2 V=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} \right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \phi^2} + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial z^2}=0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;....(1)$$Now a statement said that **if the cylinder is very long compared to the radius of the cylinder**(inner cylinder with radius $a$ and the outer cylinder(grounded) of radius $b$) **then the potential is independent of the components $\phi$ and $z$, and depends on $r$ only.** $\;$And we can write the equation $(1)$ as $$\vec \nabla^2 V=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} \right)=0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;....(2)\;\;\;\;\; [i.e.,\;only\;the\;r\;component\;is\;present]$$ Now I did not understand how this statement is true. **Why** and **how** the potential is not dependent on the other components $\phi$ and $z$ if the cylinder is too long compared to the radius? And what if the length of the cylinder is comparable to the radius of the cylinder, then should we consider the $\phi$ and $z$ components also? Please explain why we are neglecting these components before?

Thanks in advance.

Peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to symmetries along and about the $z$-axis. If the cylinder is infinitely long, any two points $(r, z_1, \phi)$ and $(r, z_2, \phi)$ are effectively indistinguishable as far as the potential is concerned. Why should the potential be any more or any less at $z=z_2$ than at $z=z_1$ if the cylinder is infinite and the charge density is the same everywhere? Each point sees the same charge distribution (relative to itself).

This argument also applies to $\phi$, except it doesn't require the cylinder to be infinitely long. Would you see any difference when you look toward the cylinder from the point $(r, z, \phi_1)$ and the point $(r, z, \phi_2)$, regardless of how long the cylinder is?

Comment: Means you are trying to say that the potential is independent of the component $\phi$, no matter how long the cylinder is or how short the cylinder is, provided the charge density is constant throughout the cylinder. But we can neglect the $z$ component only if the cylinder is infinitely long with constant charge density. If the height is comparable to radius, then we have to consider the $z$ component. Isn't it?

Comment: That is correct. The charge density doesn't actually need to be constant for the potential to have no $\phi$ dependence. The charge density just needs to be independent of $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you very much.